# How to distinguish if a script is run by user manually or by trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, button, triggers, menu, difference

I want to check if the code is being run by trigger or manually, by user using custom menu or button, for example,  for this logging situation:

```
if(scriptIsRunByUserManually()) 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Deploy successful");
else 
  console.log("Deploy successful");
```

How can I implement **scriptIsRunByUserManually()**?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the event object `e`

```
function kgoydiys(e){
    if(typeof e !== "undefined") 
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Deploy successful");
    else 
      console.log("Deploy successful")
}
```